# How to float two images right without the second one going to new line?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have two images I want to float right and keep on the same line. but what happens is mastercard image is on the right while visa card image gets floated right on the new line. Any help? Thank you

HTML:

```
  <label>
      <img src="{% static 'img/Mastercard.png' %}" style="float:right">
  </label>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <label>
      <img src="{% static 'img/Visa.png' %}" style="float:right">
  </label>
  <div class="clear"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear {
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the cleared div between them?

Comment: Even removing it won't make a difference

Comment: remove it and it will make a difference ...by the way you don't need float with image, use text-align

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to implement.

### html

```
<div id="container">
  <label> <img src="./react-logo.png" /> </label>
  <label> <img src="./pic_angular.jpg" /> </label>
</div>
```

### css

```
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }

  #container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
```

### result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to remove the first `<div class="clear"></div>` from your
   HTML markup as **div** is **block level** element that's why your second
   image is starting from the new line.
2. Also it's best to use `text-align: right` instead of using `float:right`. By using text-align property instead of float **clear class** will no longer needed.

You can write as:

```
<div style="text-align: right">
    <img src="{% static 'img/Mastercard.png' %}">
    <img src="{% static 'img/Visa.png' %}">
</div>
```

Comment: Overall, you will get a quite different result with `text-align: right` than with `float: right`.